# Razor form with dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, html, razor

Help me understand how to construct this.
Everyone and every example on the INet seems to think the only purpose of a Razor v3 asp.net form page that utilizes a DropDownList to have no other purpose but to present the drop down on the page absent any other context.

What I am doing is building a data entry page to enable a user to create a record of an Item ... think pencils, or socks, or cars ... in a database.  Two, but not the only, attributes of an Item are 1) it's order quantity {1, 2, 3, ...} and ...here is where my trouble starts...  2) it's unit of measure, UOM, {Each, Case, Weight, ...}

I have a page that has a model for the Item.  And this works just fine.  Now I'm trying to change the UOM field on the page from a TextBoxFor() to a DropDownList().

How do I populate the drop down with a discreet list of options based on UOMModel where the page is based on ItemModel?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using

Comment: that is 100's of lines.  Where I am at the moment is the ItemModel class now has a List<UOMModel>GetOptions() method.  The method calls UOMModel.GetAllOptions().  The page uses ItemModel ~ so now the page as access to the List<UOMModel>.  So how do I get the list into the the @Html of DropDownList?

Comment: DropDownList or DropDownListFor uses a list of SelectListItem objects - simply convert the data to a SelectListItem object and set it as the source of the list within the view...

Comment: Show me?  My brain is broken I think today.  The is ItemModel          public virtual List<UOMModel> GetAllOptions()
        {
            UOMOptions o = new UOMOptions();
            return o.GetAllOptions();
        }     // it is 'virtual' becasue i'm using nhibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Brian Mains said in his comment you need to convert the data to the `SelectList` class in order to use it with a `DropDownList`. You can do this:

```
    public SelectList GetSelectList(List<UOMModel> model)
    {

        var selectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            selectListItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Value, Text = item.Text});
        }

        return new SelectList(selectListItem, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

Then use a `ViewBag` to pass it to your View:

```
//Action
ViewBag.UOMList = GetSelectList(UOMList);

//View
@Html.DropDownList("UOM", ViewBag.UOMList as SelectList, new { })
```

Comment: Oh! Gosh.  The whole that that was escaping me is the use of ViewBag.  Thanks Man!!  I was thinking there had to be some implementation without using foreach().  But okay.

Comment: You're welcome dude, remember to vote it up if it was useful ;)

Comment: Super Vote Up to you.  Thanks.  Like a charm.  only wish I hadn't had to take so long to come back to this.